# creating grunt task accessing passed values

Tags: javascript, plugins, gruntjs

this is about a particular grunt-plugin that is not working for me but also a general query.

The plug in is [grunt-xmlpoke](https://github.com/bdukes/grunt-xmlpoke).  The issue is that in one's Gruntfile.js you define something like this:

```
xmlpoke: {
    options: {
       xpath: '//title',
       value: 'The Good Parts'
    },
    files: {
      'dest.xml': 'src.xml'
    },
},
```

My understanding is that inside the

```
grunt.registerMultiTask(
```

you would have access to a "this.options" object and a "this.files" object.  However what I find is that the this.files property is undefined. Further when I look at the "this.data" object I find that it has property called "dest.xml" which has a value of "src.xml".

**Edit**

I guess it's not so strange that it's doing the property value thing.  That makes sense.  So let's focus on how one should get values from the files input

**End Edit**

This seems counter intuitive and I've failed to find the proper way of accessing what the user passes in.

If you can either make xmlpoke work or tell me how you are supposed to do it or preferably both :) that would be great.

Thanks,
Raif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a task that is a multitask, you need to give it a *target*. This should have been documented in the plugin, but basically change your config to the following:

```
xmlpoke: {
    build: {
        options: {
            xpath: '//title',
            value: 'The Good Parts'
        },
        files: {
            'dest.xml': 'src.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

That should give you the output.

Comment: this indeed is the case.  Thank you.  Still having problems with the plugin but when it comes time to create some custom tasks I will have this under my belt.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the docs are insufficient.  I just wasted a half hour trying to get the samples in the docs working only to have realized it needed to be configured with a target.